# An error trying to debug an Android application's shared library using IDA Pro

Tags: android, debugging, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm trying to debug a shared library of an Android application.

The process is:

1. adb push IDA Pro/dbgsrv/android_server /data/local/tmp
2. adb shell, cd data/local/tmp, ./android_server
3. adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946
4. Set the IDA pro debuggger to Remote ARM Linux/Android debugger
5. In Debugger->Process options, Application and Input file are set to shared library directory, Hostname is set to localhost, and Port is set to 23946
6. Click Debugger->Attach to process, and select the app

After that, it give me the following error:

> The debugger could not attach to the selected process. This can
> perhaps indicate the process was just terminated, or that you don't
> have the necessary privileges.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you executed the on-device IDA debugger with root permissions (via `su`)? Without root permissions native debugging will not work. If it still does not work the app may implement anti-debugging mechanisms.

Comment: Yes, I'm executing the android_server with su. I was assuming that an anti-debugging might have something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

## Debugging a library using IDA Pro and Android

Debugging a library requires:

- IDA Pro Debug server to be on the device and running
- IDA Pro open to the library of interest
- A simple driver app to `dlopen` the library
- Some breakpoints or settings to suspend execution

### Driver

You will open the `.so` file in IDA Pro and then set up the debugger to call the driver app. You'll probably want to call some functions too, because otherwise this will be a rather boring exercise. A little sketch approximating this will do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *load_library(char *library_path) {
    void *handle = dlopen(library_path, RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        char *msg = dlerror();
        printf("%s\n", msg);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        printf("Opened library.\n");
        printf("Handle: %p\n", handle);
    }

    // Get an address that is exported so we can get the slide
    void *entry_point_ptr = dlsym(handle, "AnExportedSymbol");

    Dl_info library_info;
    dladdr(entry_point_ptr, &library_info);
    void *library_base = (void *)library_info.dli_fbase;

    printf("Library base addr: %p\n", library_base);
    printf("Function offset: 0x%x\n", entry_point_ptr - library_base);
    return library_base;
}
```

### IDA Pro Remote Android Debugger

[image: Remote Debugger Options]

### IDA Pro Debug Server

Start the server so IDA has someone to talk to. It is not strictly necessary to copy the binary every single time, but it also doesn't matter much.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

pushd "/Applications/IDAPro/ida.app/Contents/MacOS/dbgsrv"
adb push android_server /data/local/tmp/
adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/android_server
adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946
adb shell su -c ./data/local/tmp/android_server
```

### Start debugging

Now that everything is set up correctly, you should be able to debug the library directly from IDA Pro. You may want to adjust the Debugger options to suspend on load or at least set some breakpoints.

### Calling a function pointer directly

Calling unexported functions can be achieved by creating a rough prototype of the function, getting the offset in IDA Pro, adding the base and calling it.

```
int get_random_ptr = 0x2001; // Hypothetically
typedef uint32_t get_random(void *buf, uint32_t buflen, uint32_t flags); // prototype of something

get_random *gr = (get_random *)library_base + get_random_ptr + 1; // The one is because I'm calling ARM 32-bit Thumb code
uint32_t result = gr(seed, 32, 0);
```